# Javascript Regex: How to extract html tag values in group?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Context**

I'm new to regex (still practicing) and I'm trying to extract `script src` or `link href` values from tags (for education purposes).

**Given following html**

```
<!-- hello -->
    <script src="1.js"></script>
    <script src="2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css"/>
<!-- world -->
```

**I'd want to get**

array of: `1.js`, `2.js` and `3.css`

**I've tried**

This is the regex I've did so far, but meh.

```
/(?:<!-- hello -->\s*?)([\s\S]*?)(?:\s?<!-- world -->)/gmi
```

Of course, I have to replace `[\s\S]*?` with something better but I've tried a lot of combinations and none of them worked.

Regards.

**Update**

Only scripts between `<!-- xxx --><!-- xxx-->` tags should be matched.

Following should not match:

```
<!-- foo-->
    <script src="4.js"></script>
    <script src="5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="6.css"/>
<!-- bar-->
```

Comment: You have completed Step 1. Now, proceed to Step 2, just use the `/(?:src|href)="([^"]*)"/g` and grab Group 1 values.

Comment: without completing first step, it's not possible to grab directly other ones?

Comment: In JS, no.......

Comment: Oh, understood! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: I suggest that you write it yourself, this way you will learn better. Just use my comment for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the regex

```
<!-- hello -->([\S\s]+)<!-- world -->
```

to extract the valid string in the first group see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ89gj/1)

then you can use the regex

```
<(?:script src.*|link.*href)="(\w+\.\w+)
```

all matches would be in group 1

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpQh75/1)

Comment: you can extract text between <!-- xxx --> and then apply this regex on the resulting string

Answer (score 1):

So, as Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned, it should be done in steps, because it's not possible in JS to directly get the result.

First you'll have to grab elements between `<!-- xxx --><!-- xxx -->` tags and then use global search on the result.

Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew!

Comment: If it's the correct solution, mark it as the answer :)

Comment: can't yet, at least for two days :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element like

```
<name attribute=value attribute="value" attribute='value'>
```

this regex could be used to find successively each attribute name and value

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?
```

Applied on:

```
<a href=test.html class=xyz>
<a href="test.html" class="xyz">
<a href='test.html' class="xyz">
```

it would yield:

```
'href' => 'test.html'
'class' => 'xyz'
```

Comment: You can try something like
http://regexr.com/
Or,
https://regex101.com/

As per your need :-)